# How do i validate two inputs inside a HTML form using JavaScript from a function with two variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a HTML form and assigned two inputs into it, One for username and one for mobile number. I then made a function in Java Script and made two variables a and b for username and mobile number but on submitting the form the function seem to work only for one of the inputs , can someone provide a solution to this ?
I am expecting the messages assigned for username and mobile number to appear in the span tag on submittion of the form

i am providing the HTML and Java Script code below

```
<form onSubmit="return valid()">
     HOME
     <p><input type="text" id="user_name" value=""><span id="msg"></span></p>
     Mobile
     <p><input type="text" id="mobile" value=""><span id="msg"></span></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
```

JavaScript Document

```
function valid()
{
    var correct_way = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var a=document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    if(a=="")
   {
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" please insert value";
       return false;

   }
    if(a.length<3)
   {
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" username cannot be less than 3 charachters";
       return false;

   }
    if(a.length>15)
   {
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" username cannot be greater than 15 charachters";
       return false;
   }
    if(a==correct_way)
   {
     true;
   }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" username should be only charachter";
        return false;
    }

    var b=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    if(b=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" please enter mobile number";
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(b))
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" only numbers are allowed";
        return false;

    }
    if(b.length<10)
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" mobile number must be 10 digit";
        return false;
    }
     if(b.length>10)
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" mobile number must be 10 digit";
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: In order for us to help you diagnose problems in your code, you're going to have to show that code and explain those problems.  This may also be a good time for you to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Using the debugger you can place a breakpoint in your code to pause execution and step through that execution one line at a time, observing the runtime behaviors and runtime values of your variables.  When you do that, you can find which specific operation produces an unexpected result.  What is that operation?  What is the result?

Comment: Please don't use `>` when posting code.

Comment: new to the site sorry

Comment: You should show how you are including the javascript code and show if you got any console errors.

Comment: BTW you can use built in validation to avoid this hazzle: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: It's because of you if statements, checking value for "a" then execute proper action. Then your program doesnt continue to look for "b" value. The else in checking "a" value doesn't let the condition to move forward to "b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   function valid()
{
    var correct_way = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var a=document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    if(a=="")
   {
  document.getElementById("user_name").nextSibling.innerHTML=" please insert value";
       return false;

   }
    if(a.length<3)
   {
  document.getElementById("user_name").nextSibling.innerHTML=" username cannot be less than 3 charachters";
       return false;

   }
    if(a.length>15)
   {
   
    document.getElementById("user_name").nextSibling.innerHTML=" username cannot be greater than 15 charachters";
       return false;
   }
   
   if(!correct_way.test(a)){
   document.getElementById("user_name").nextSibling.innerHTML=" username should be only charachter";
   return false;
   }

    var b=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    if(b=="")
    {
  document.getElementById("mobile").nextSibling.innerHTML=" please enter mobile number";
        return false;
    }
    if(isNaN(b))
    {
        document.getElementById("mobile").nextSibling.innerHTML=" only numbers are allowed";
        return false;

    }
    if(b.length<10)
    {
        document.getElementById("mobile").nextSibling.innerHTML="  mobile number must be 10 digit";
        return false;
    }
     if(b.length>10)
    {
  document.getElementById("mobile").nextSibling.innerHTML="  mobile number must be 10 digit";
        return false;
    }

}
```

```html
  <form onSubmit="return valid()">
     HOME
     <p><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value=""><span class="user_name"></span></p>
     Mobile
     <p><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value=""><span class="mobile"></span></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
```

Comment: Now messages assigned for username and mobile number to appear in the span tag on submittion of the form. Please check.

Comment: thanks it worked ,was i not writing the regEx pattern properly ?

Comment: your regEx is fine. you can use that also.

Comment: I edited the post and using your regEx. It's working fine. Please check

Comment: oh thanks even my pattern worked perfectly but what was wrong in this ?, if(a==correct_way)
   {
     true;
   }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" username should be only charachter";
        return false;
    }

Comment: 1)  a==correct_way, this is not a way to match regEx, 2) if(a==correct_way) { true; } - this true is not using in code because after submit the form it will check return value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bec you are not returning any true statements with the b part. You have only error messages

Comment: i have used if(isNaN(b)) for b to automatically check for string values ,i just want the messages to run for both the inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML 5 form validation please do because it will do a lot of this stuff for you and is natively supported by modern browsers.

If not, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but a few things I can see is you will return true before validating the second variable so put a return true at the end of the function and only return false when validation fails.  Second once you return true the form will submit so your page is going to reload and unless you use your server side code to populate the span tags you won't see anything in them because the page was reloaded.  The only other thing is to make sure your js doesn't get cached if you are loading it from a js file.  Please let me know some more specifics on what is happening and I will be able to help more.

Maybe missing the return in front of true also but then everything after this statement would be unreachable.

```
   if(a==correct_way)
   {
     true;
   }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" username should be only charachter";
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i had to return true the first variable a for username because i used a RegEx pattern and i had to check it and i checked for string charachters in the second variable by using (isNaN(b)) but when i am submitting the form the messages work for only var a also the regEx is sort of not working

Comment: if you are trying to match the regex you need to use correct_way.test(a) not the == operator. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp